# google recaptcha in colorbox IE can't enter text

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox, recaptcha

I'm trying to use new google recaptcha in ajax window with colorbox. But there is a problem in IE 9, 10, 11: I can enter nothing in text field. Without colorbox it's allright.
Here's my code

```
<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer" src="//www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?ver=1"></script>      
    <div id="form">
        <div class="g-recaptcha" id="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?= RECAPTCHA_KEY ?>"></div>
        <button name="" id="sendNotice" type="submit">Send</button>
    </div>
            <script>
                function showNoticePopup(productId, shopProductId) {
                    $.colorbox({
                        href: '#form',
                        onComplete: function() {
                            grecaptcha.render('g-recaptcha', {
                                'sitekey' : '<?= RECAPTCHA_KEY ?>'
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            showNoticePopup();
            </script>
```

Does anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution.
The problem was in colorbox option called `trapFocus`.
If you has this problem just set this option to `false` and enjoy :)

Similar problem was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27886618/problems-with-new-google-recaptcha-in-ie-when-inside-modal-or-dialog) for bootstrap modal window.