# Override a stock BootStrap javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, bootstrap-modal

I'm generating a bootstrap modal using the following plugin which loads a form into a modal dynamically.
https://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/

```
BootstrapDialog.show({
            message: $('<div></div>').load('remote.html')
        });
```

This page then loads another modal which is google reCaptcha control. This control has a button which becomes unresponsive.

I've figured that I need to override a function that natively comes in bootstrap as mentioned in this link [Problems with new Google reCAPTCHA in IE when inside modal or dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27886618/problems-with-new-google-recaptcha-in-ie-when-inside-modal-or-dialog/28965638#28965638)

This single line of code should do the overriding.

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function () { };
```

It shouldn't be that difficult but I have spent almost 2 hours trying to figure out why my function isn't overriding the original BS function?

Also, if I put the above line of code in bootstrap.js file, then the override works. Anywhere else, it doesn't.

The code works in Firefox and Chrome, but fails in IE which is out of context but the fix is for IE.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to setup a fiddle showcasing the problem?

Comment: @MattWay Not sure if I can do that because the modal is loaded dynamically on a click of a link. But here's the scenario. An ajax call 'get's a form that is loaded into a modal. That modal in turn loads reCaptcha content into another modal. There's some issue with the reCaptcha modal not getting the focus in IE which is the reason why I'm trying to remove the default constructor. Also, overriding works when I add it to bootstrap.js file but any code within html file gets overlooked.